# Java program to connect to remote MySQL db (having ssh server running)

Tags: java, mysql, ssh

I want to develop a java swing application. in which, the MySQL db will be stored on only one PC. and the software can access that db from anywhere.
I am new to this type of JDBC connection.
so, I was searching about possible ways to create such remote connection.
so I got following possible solutions:

1) I can host that db on web. so that's worked for me. I tried to host my db on *freesqldatabase.com* which allows remote db connection.

2) I heard about ssh tunneling. This topic is also new to me.
So, first I created the ssh server on the PC which is having MySQL db.
So, this pc is currently running ssh server.
then I tried putty software on client machine to connect to my ssh server. and its working. I am able to give access to the client machine through ssh tunnel.

so my remote connection is working now.
but i want to execute the JDBC connection from client computer. to connect to the ssh running computer which is having db.

I am familiar with the db connection using IP address,
like,

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://server ip address/databaseName";
           Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url,"username","password");
```

So will you please tell me, about the ssh connection in Java programming?
How can I connect to the server(PC having ssh running and MySQL db) from client PC?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Are you asking you have database and application on different machine and you want to use your database in your application, which is on different server ??

Comment: yes.you are right.

Comment: then why do you need tunneling and all those stuffs ??

Answer (score 0):

[JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) is what you are looking for.

This library is doing the same thing like you have done, tunneling the local machine to remote machine. JSch will start tunnelling  and the jdbc will connect thru the JSch setting.

This is example from [here](http://www.journaldev.com/235/java-mysql-ssh-jsch-jdbc).

```
package com.journaldev.java.ssh

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.sql.Connection;


public class MySqlConnOverSSH {

    /**
     * Java Program to connect to remote database through SSH using port forwarding
     * @author Pankaj@JournalDev
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        int lport=5656;
        String rhost="secure.journaldev.com";
        String host="secure.journaldev.com";
        int rport=3306;
        String user="sshuser";
        String password="sshpassword";
        String dbuserName = "mysql";
        String dbpassword = "mysql123";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:"+lport+"/mydb";
        String driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        Connection conn = null;
        Session session= null;
        try{
            //Set StrictHostKeyChecking property to no to avoid UnknownHostKey issue
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();
            System.out.println("Connected");
            int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
            System.out.println("localhost:"+assinged_port+" -> "+rhost+":"+rport);
            System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

            //mysql database connectivity
            Class.forName(driverName).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, dbuserName, dbpassword);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
            System.out.println("DONE");
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            if(conn != null && !conn.isClosed()){
                System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
                conn.close();
            }
            if(session !=null && session.isConnected()){
                System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
                session.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

im never done this but i just config my local machine to start tunneling to remote server when machine is up.

Comment: ohh thank you...i will try it...and let you know soon

Comment: @Sh4m- will you please tell me what is lport in above code?... i was trying lport as 3306 but its giving me error

Comment: Connected
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:3306 cannot be bound.
Closing SSH Connection

Comment: lport is ssh localhost port for tunnelling... i think you no need to change jdbc the port..

Comment: means? i didnt understand.sorry

Comment: now when i save lport=22, its also giving me error.

Comment: Connected          
localhost:22 -> **myip**:3306                
Port Forwarded         
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
Closing SSH Connection

Comment: its displaying connected >>then port forwarded >> then>> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple to understand, when you are communicating to database server you need to have address of the server (i.e. ip address) and port number, since each application on machine uses specific port to communicate.

Now, since you need to access your database for your application, which is deployed on other server. You need to deploy application and database on the network, so that they can communicate using ip address and port number.

For your testing you could use LAN. You can have two machine within lan and assign some ip address to them and then use database server ip address to create JDBC connection.

I really don't know the use of tunneling in your case. When things can be done easily why are you trying complex or unknown approach ?

Comment: sorry...but i already know about LAN Conecction for mysql db...and the code given in the db is tested for that... but i am not saying that, the client computer will be in the LAN... thats why i am trying tunneling here...

Comment: you just mentioned in other comment that database resides in different server. right ? I gave example of LAN, just to make you understand.